# Cuneiform library crashes when is called via JNI bridge

Tags: java, gdb, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I am writing a Java application, from which I call (via another library) functions from [Cuneiform](https://launchpad.net/cuneiform-linux) OCR library. Unfortunately, I have a crash in very strange place, and I need the advice of the community.

The program crashes on the first code line of [`RVERLINE_MarkLines()`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~jpakkane/cuneiform-linux/trunk/view/476/cuneiform_src/Kern/rverline/src/root/vl_kern.cpp#L114), called from [`RSL_SetImportData()`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~jpakkane/cuneiform-linux/trunk/view/476/cuneiform_src/Kern/rshelllines/src/rshelllines.cpp#L306), in a very first code position (initialization of variable `lti`). I have checked all passed variables in `gdb`: they all make sense and seem to be valid. It looks like the stack get corrupted, as a tried to reshuffle source lines in `RVERLINE_MarkLines()` without any success.

The same code for the same input data works OK when is invoked from C++ code (CPP CLI → some library → Cuneiform library), but breaks when invoked from JVM (JVM → some library → Cuneiform library).

As I am newbie with `gdb`, perhaps someone can give me a hint, *how can I find out the reason of the crash*? Where to look at and what to pay attention to?

Many thanks in advance.

Stack trace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0xb7564b70 (LWP 416)]
RVERLINE_MarkLines (hCComp=0xb28a2708, hCPage=0xb28a28d0)
    at cuneiform-1.0.0.orig/cuneiform_src/Kern/rverline/src/root/vl_kern.cpp:120
120             LinesTotalInfo  lti = {0};  // Структура хранения линий
(gdb) bt
#0  RVERLINE_MarkLines (hCComp=0xb28a2708, hCPage=0xb28a28d0)
    at cuneiform-1.0.0.orig/cuneiform_src/Kern/rverline/src/root/vl_kern.cpp:120
#1  0xb3b7d727 in RSL_SetImportData (dwType=1, pData=0xb7559b50)
    at cuneiform-1.0.0.orig/cuneiform_src/Kern/rshelllines/src/rshelllines.cpp:332
#2  0xb3bdca96 in RLINE_LinesPass1 (hCPage=0xb28a28d0, hCCOM=0xb28a2708, phCLINE=0xb45a34fc, pgneed_clean_line=0xb45a3630, sdl=0,
    lang=0 '\000') at cuneiform-1.0.0.orig/cuneiform_src/Kern/rline/sources/newline.cpp:224
#3  0xb3b70bb2 in SearchNewLines (Image=0xb7559e1c)
    at cuneiform-1.0.0.orig/cuneiform_src/Kern/rstuff/sources/main/normalise.cpp:230
#4  0xb3b70d78 in Normalise (Image=0xb7559e1c)
    at cuneiform-1.0.0.orig/cuneiform_src/Kern/rstuff/sources/main/normalise.cpp:189
#5  0xb3b6d900 in RSTUFF_RSNormalise (Image=0xb7559e1c, vBuff=0xb31ba008, Size=500000, vWork=0xb318e008, SizeWork=180000)
    at cuneiform-1.0.0.orig/cuneiform_src/Kern/rstuff/sources/main/dll.cpp:352
#6  0xb458919a in Layout (lpdata=0x0) at cuneiform-1.0.0.orig/cuneiform_src/Kern/puma/c/partlayout.cpp:203
#7  0xb458b963 in PUMA_XFinalRecognition () at cuneiform-1.0.0.orig/cuneiform_src/Kern/puma/main/puma.cpp:590
...
#20 0xb77d5d0c in jni_CallStaticVoidMethod () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.22/jre/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so
#21 0x08049b98 in JavaMain ()
#22 0xb7fc3955 in start_thread (arg=0xb7564b70) at pthread_create.c:300
#23 0xb7f35e7e in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/clone.S:130
```

Additional info:

- Platform Linux x32
- SUN JVM 1.6.0.22
- GCC 4.4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your crash looks like a typical case of stack exhaustion.

When you call the library from C++, you probably use main thread, which usually has at least 8MB. When you call it from Java, you call it from some thread other than main, which may have a much smaller stack (for example, [for Linux x32 default stack size is 320k](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#threads_oom) – that may vary for different platforms and different JVM implementations).

The following commands should allow you to confirm the problem:

```
(gdb) p/x $esp
(gdb) shell cat /proc/<pid>/maps  # replace <pid> with the pid of crashing
                                  # thread, e.g. 416 above.
```

You will likely see that `$esp` points into inaccessible (guard) page (which has `---p` permissions). If this is correct, you must either create the thread which uses the OCR library with larger stack, or ensure that the library is only accessed from the main thread. You can do it by using e.g. `-Xss1024K` JVM argument (will set the stack size for all threads) or [`-XX:MainThreadStackSize=1024K`](http://docs.hp.com/en/JAVAPROGUIDE/hotspot.html#-XX%3aMainThreadStackSize) (will set the stack size only for main thread on *HP-UX JVM*).

For example it is OK for `$esp` value `0xb755a000` to be within this memory segment (has `rw` permissions):

```
b7517000-b7565000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0          [threadstack:0004d494]
```